# Moblog parameter to pull sender from email?

Tags: fields

I have Moblog running as I'd hoped except how to pull the sender's name from the email. Since the subject line automagically becomes {title}, it seems it should be as simple, but I can't find documentation anywhere, and am drawing a blank.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Jo

Comment: {sender_email} works, but I'd prefer the name. But, this may be best for our little group, as some do not have their email display name set correctly!

Found it in the mod.moblog.php file when I steeled myself enough to open it.

Hope this helps someone else.

Peace, Jo

Answer (score 1):

You don't detail where you are trying to "push" the sender's name after you've pulled it.

If you want to use it to set the entry Author, you can do that with the "User Authorization" override:
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/moblog/index.html#user-authorization

Or you can push data into fields like this:
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/moblog/index.html#field

Comment: Thanks; yes, I'm pushing it into fields. The syntax {sender_email} reveals the author's email address; I would prefer to reveal only the author's name (several people will have the posting address) without invoking overrides.